# Can't get jStorage to pull user object - keeps saying "user is null"

Tags: javascript, mysql, jstorage

I can't get jStorage to work. When I test it with the following code the result is "user is null" How do I get user to return the proper value and also target its attributes that exist in the mySql database.

```
var user = $.jStorage.get('user');
console.log('user is ' + user);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set user before get it?
try something like this

```
var user = $.jStorage.get("user");
if(!user){
        user = 'SomeUser';
    $.jStorage.set("user",value);
}
```